# ng-change, directive, $watch all not working in $mdDialog page

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I was trying to re-produce my problem. But it is a little bit complex. So I post my problem here first to see if anyone has the same experience while I am working on re-producing it.

I have a button A on my main page. When I click this button, it will popup (using $mdDialog) a window displaying a html page B. There is a button C on this page B. When I click it, it will popup a window displaying a html page D.

So page D has the following structure: (it has a controller file named dCtrl.js)

```
<uib-accordion>
<div uib-accordion-group>
...some input fields here
</div>
<div uib-accordion-group>
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
    <label>Telephone Number</label>
    <input name="phoneNum" type="text" ng-required="true" id = "phoneNum"
           ng-model="newCustomer.Phone" ng-change="formatTelNo()"
           ng-pattern="/^[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/"
           placeholder="(###) ###-####" />                   
</md-input-container>
</div>
<div uib-accordion-group>
...some input fields here
</div>
</ubi-accordion>
```

What I want to acchive is: When user inputs the telephone number, I will convert it to format (xxx) XXX-XXXX.

The first solution I tried is using directive, because I have the directive ready. I used the directive on my main page. It works well. However, here it seems the directive is not triggered.

The second solution I tried is ng-change = formatTelNo(), but it cannot be triggered, either.

The third solution I tried is $watch,

```
$scope.$watch('newCustomer.Phone',
    function (newVal, oldVal) {do sth here},true)
```

This $watch cannot be triggered, either.
By the way, other functions in the dCtrl.js all works.

So I guess this is something related to $scope of using $mdDialog? Or it is something related to using md-input-container or uib-accordion? Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

FYI
My directive looks like this:

```
'use strict';
app.directive('phoneInput', function ($filter, $browser) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var listener = function () {
            var value = $element.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
            $element.val($filter('tel')(value, false));
        };

        // This runs when we update the text field
        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            return viewValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').slice(0, 10);
        });

        // This runs when the model gets updated on the scope directly and keeps our view in sync
        ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
            $element.val($filter('tel')(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue, false));
        };

        $element.bind('change', listener);
        $element.bind('keydown', function (event) {
            var key = event.keyCode;
            // If the keys include the CTRL, SHIFT, ALT, or META keys, or the arrow keys, do nothing.
            // This lets us support copy and paste too
            if (key == 91 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (37 <= key && key <= 40)) {
                return;
            }
            $browser.defer(listener); // Have to do this or changes don't get picked up properly
        });

        $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
            $browser.defer(listener);
        });
    }

};
}).filter('tel', function () {
  return function (tel) {
console.log(tel);
if (!tel) { return ''; }

var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
  return tel;
}

var country, city, number;

switch (value.length) {
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
  city = value;
  break;

default:
  city = value.slice(0, 3);
  number = value.slice(3);
}

if (number) {
  if (number.length > 3) {
    number = number.slice(0, 3) + '-' + number.slice(3, 7);
  }
  else {
    number = number;
  }

  return ("(" + city + ") " + number).trim();
}
    else {
      return "(" + city;
    }

  };
});
```

Now I can get my directive triggered, but everything is undefined such as element, attrs or ngModelCtrl.

Comment: We need more code to figure out where your mistake is, because it's working perfectly fine on my part. Can you provide a small code pen with mock functions ?

Comment: Work on fixing the directive that formats the telephone number. You can console log the scope from inside the directive and access the [ng-model controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) API from there.

Comment: Provide the code for the directive that formats the telephone number. It is likely written erroneously. Custom input formatter directives should avoid using a scope.

Comment: any suggestion why ng-change and $watch are not working?